# Assign colors in specific order in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to loop array and assign colors in specific order to each array element.

> First, fifty, ninth and so on should have **red** color.
>
> Second, sixth, tenth and so on should have **green** color.
>
> Third,Seventh, eleventh and so on should have **blue** color.
>
> Fourth, eighth, twelfth so on should have **yellow** color.

[Link to Fiddle Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/perija/8p1hrsq0/)

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
const arr = [1, 'a', 3, 'b', 55, 69, 71, 8, 91, 10];
let color;

arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  switch (i) {
    case i % 1:
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case i % 2:
      color = 'green';
      break;
    case i % 3:
      color = 'blue';
      break;
    case i % 4:
      color = 'yellow';
      break;

    default:
      color = 'red';
      break;
  }

  console.log('color:', el, i, color);
});
```

Comment: That's not how `switch ... case` works

Comment: Why would the tenth element be both green and blue?

Comment: @Andreas and how should i solve this, what is better approach?

Comment: @Andy that was a typo, it's fixed now.

Comment: Not with a broken `switch..case...` - Read the documentation how it works, and then replace it with `if...else...` or find a way how you could use the the index `i` to access the colors in `colors`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably avoid the switch like this:

```js
const colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
const arr = [1, "a", 3, "b", 55, 69, 71, 8, 91, 10];
let color;

arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  color = colors[i % colors.length];
  console.log("color:", el, i, color);
});
```

`i % colors.length` gives you the color index

Tip: you can add more colors to your array and it will still work

Comment: Why the magic number `4`?

Comment: it's the length of the color array, you might be interested by the last line of the answer ;)

Comment: _"t's the length of the color array"_ - I know. _"you might be interested..."_ - Why not just fix it all together? There's no good reason why OP should stay with a hardcoded `4` instead of a generic `colors.length`

Comment: here you go sir ! Next time please be nice and make it clear that you request a change, I might end up helping someone else with the time saved

Comment: Thanks Apolo for the help, and I agree with you, @Andreas was too judgy and with his comments he didn't help and made things more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a couple changes.  `switch(i)` should be `switch ((i + 1) % 4)` , so that you switch on the evaluated expression of `index + 1 mod 4` (plus 1 so that you don't mod' on `0`, which is the first index and so that you get usable results).  Also, your cases should be `case 1:`, `case 2:`, etc..  Take a look below:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
const arr = [1, 'a', 3, 'b', 55, 69, 71, 8, 91, 10];
let color;

arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  switch ((i + 1) % 4) {
    case 1:
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case 2:
      color = 'green';
      break;
    case 3:
      color = 'blue';
      break;
    case 0:
      color = 'yellow';
      break;

    default:
      color = 'red';
      break;
  }

  console.log('color:', el, i, color);
});
```